# Oozie co-ordinator application not working for more than one hour difference of start and end times

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Problem with my oozie co-ordinator application.
Case 1 :
For -
**start** = "2012-09-07 13:00Z" **end**="2012-09-07 16:00Z" **frequency**="coord:hour(1)"
No of actions : 1 (expected is 3)
Nominal Times -
1) 2012-09-07 13:00Z (Two more are expected. 2012-09-07 14:00Z,2012-09-07 15:00Z)
Case 2 :
For -
**start** = "2012-09-07 13:00Z" **end**="2012-09-07 16:00Z" **frequency** = "coord:minutes(10)"
No of actions : 6 (expected is 18)
Nominal Times :
1) 2012-09-07 13:00Z
2) 2012-09-07 13:10Z
3) 2012-09-07 13:20Z
4) 2012-09-07 13:30Z
5) 2012-09-07 13:40Z
6) 2012-09-07 13:50Z (12 more are expected. 2012-09-07 14:00Z,2012-09-07 14:10Z and so on..).

Generalization based on observation :
Any frequency from **coord:minutes(1)** to **coord:minutes(59)**, the nominal times are perfectly calculated, but only till one hour.
Please suggest if I am missing anything here. Using oozie 2.0, trying with a basic co-ordinator app which is working fine for :
**start** = "2012-09-07 13:00Z" **end** = "2012-09-07 13:30Z" **frequency** = "coord:minutes(10)"

Comment: Mind formatting your code? Your question looks kinda funny right now.

Answer (score 2):

Do the 6 actions finish successfully? There are 3 conditions that Oozie Coordinator will check before invoke 1 new action: 1) data dependency 2) frequency 3) concurrency limit. Any of these 3 conditions may stop the action from being started. It will be helpful if you can show us the coordinator's xml file.

Comment: Apologies for an inappropriate question. The issue was, when I am using the dryrun feature of oozie. The property oozie.service.CoordJobMatLookupTriggerService.materialization.window was set to 3600 (which is 1 hour), implying that the materializations will be prepared only for 1 hour, and oozie.service.CoordJobMatLookupTriggerService.lookup.interval was set to 300, i.e every 5 minutes materializations would be refreshed.

Comment: So, I was able to see only the materializations till one hour, and essentially, there was no issue. Had there been every other thing alright, it would have run as per the schedule. Sorry again